# C# NPOI ошибка Extern sheet is part of LinkTable при создании объекта HSSFWorkbook из FileStream

Tags: c#, excel, xls, apache-poi, poi

Код ниже работает с ошибкой: "Extern sheet is part of LinkTable". Использую NPOI 2.3.0 для работы с Excel.

```
HSSFWorkbook xlsFile;

using (var fileRead = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{ 
    try
    {
        xlsFile = new HSSFWorkbook(fileRead);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как открыть этот файл с помощью NPOI? Microsoft Office открывает этот файл и можно его пересохранить. После пересохранения изменяется размер файла в меньшую сторону и NPOI легко открывает этот файл.

Но нужна работа именно с NPOI.
Пробовал загружать файл через POIFS, а не сразу создавать объект HSSFWorkbook. Но ничего толкового не вышло.

Файл с ошибкой:
[fileWithException](https://dl.velesstroy.com/public/filewithexception--ru)

Answer (score 0):

Похожий вопрос. Может вам поможет.
[Ответ на ENG Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855813/npoi-how-to-read-file-using-npoi)

На всякий случай перепечатаю, если вдруг он потеряется.

Пример чтения:

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

//.....

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\test.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        hssfwb= new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    }

    ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheet("Arkusz1");
    for (int row = 0; row <= sheet.LastRowNum; row++)
    {
        if (sheet.GetRow(row) != null) //null is when the row only contains empty cells 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Row {0} = {1}", row, sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(0).StringCellValue));
        }
    }
}
```

По этой ссылке также находится пакет примеров по [NPIO](http://npoi.codeplex.com/releases/view/49524)

Comment: Нет, данный пример не относится к ошибке которую я описал. Ошибка появляется в строке xlsFile = new HSSFWorkbook(fileRead); при создании объекта и в итоге xlsFile == null. Дальнейшая работа невозможна. К своему запросу приложил файл образец, на котором появляется такая ошибка.

Comment: на официальном сайте также задал этот вопрос https://npoi.codeplex.com/workitem/14145
но с октября 2017 года насколько я понял поддержка прекратилась.